# How to insert unicode into mysql using maven

Tags: java, maven, unicode

I am trying to insert Unicode values into mysql database using jsp forms. But data is saved like `à´à´®àµà´¤` in the database.

What should I do?

I added

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the form. Database is also in utf8 format.

I can enter Unicode values directly into the database and retrieve it. Problem occurs when form is used

Comment: How are the values transfered from the JSP file to the database ? Is the service which is doing that correct ? Handling UTF-8 ?

Comment: is this maven related?

Comment: i am using pojo class to pass value and then using session.saveOrUpdate() to save values

Comment: ya, this is a maven project

Comment: What characters were supposed to be saved?